# Bigger picture on a computer display

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, zoom

I feel it more comfortable for my eyes to have all objects (e.g. fonts, graphics) on a screen larger. This is why I want to make the display show everything in larger proportion.

Setting the display to a smaller resolutions, doesn't seem to work fine, though. The display provides crisp picture only at its native resolution. I've also tried to search the web for zooming tools but they are made to display only a specific portions of the screen bigger, not the whole screen.

Is there any other approach to achieve that on Windows 7?

Comment: On what OS are you working? Most OSs have themes for large proportions.

Comment: I am using Win 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default way for you to do this.
You will have to set manually all the things you want.
But here are few changes you can make:

**Icons:** Right click on desktop > View > Large icons.

**Taskbar:** Right click on taskbar > Properties > Untick small taskbar buttons. Select Never Combine for bigger taskbar tabs.

**Browsers:** Hit Ctrl and + sign  or CTRL and mouse wheel for setting bigger zoom label. Browsers remember these settings for pages and next time it will open up with the bigger zoom you set on your previous visit. **Update**: As pointed out by *andyb* you can use `chrome://settings/search#zoom` to set default zoom.

**Mouse pointer:** Go into control panel and find mouse properties > Pointers > Select a scheme with big pointers. There are a few.

**Pictures:** Get [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) and again hit Ctrl and + to zoom your pics.

**Video** Get [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and fiddle with the zoom settings there also.

You can additionally download widgets, themes and other stuff if this ain't big enough.

Comment: For a browser, it would be easier to change the default page zoom rather than on every site. Chrome settings are located at `chrome://settings/search#zoom` for example.

Comment: Yep I agree. Will include it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try setting your text size larger? I know Windows has settings for font scaling;
I think you go to `Display` in the control panel, then go to settings tab, then advanced
Then under the general tab, you can set the DPI setting which will affect the font size.

You can change the size of widgets (scroll bars, etc.) by going to Control Panel/Personalisation/Window Color/Advanced Appearance settings, and you can change things like the scrollbar there. I think that's how it is in Windows 7 (not on a Windows machine at the moment).

On Windows XP, there's an appearances tab where you can set the size of widgets as well.

Comment: updated for changing the size of widgets.